# Prevent empty data upload if file upload is left empty on edit PHP

Tags: php

I have an edit page where users can update their post information (this is a non-wordpress site). The post will only show the most recently updated photo. If they do not upload any new photo, there is a blank file that is uploaded. That blank file will replace the last photo uploaded with a broken image icon since the file does not exist.

A normal photo shows up in my database as `images/filename.extension` with an id attributed to it. When a photo is not selected, empty data will be uploaded as `images/` and will have an id attributed to it, even though there is nothing there that exists.

Is it possible for me to prevent this empty file upload from occurring if there is no file selected during submission on edit?

If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is the part only pertaining to the file uploading:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES["images"]["name"]); $i++){
    $filetmp = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    $filename = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
    $filetype = $_FILES["images"]["type"][$i];
    $filepath = "images/".$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (img_name, img_path, img_type, post_id)
            VALUES ('$filename', '$filepath', '$filetype', '$id')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
```

Here is the entire edit PHP on submit:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $link = $_POST['link']; 
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start']));
    $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['end']));
    $title = $db->real_escape_string($title);
    $link = $db->real_escape_string($link);
    $description = $db->real_escape_string($description);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];    
    if($title && $description){
        if ($update = $db->prepare("UPDATE post SET title='$title', link='$link', description='$description', start='$start', end='$end' WHERE post_id=$id")) {
            $update->execute();
            $update->fetch();
            $update->close();
        }    
        if($update){
            $_SESSION['message'] =  "The offer has been updated!";
        }else{
            $_SESSION['message'] =  "error";
        }
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Please make sure required fields are filled out.";
    }  
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES["images"]["name"]); $i++){
        $filetmp = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $filename = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
        $filetype = $_FILES["images"]["type"][$i];
        $filepath = "images/".$filename;
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO images (img_name, img_path, img_type, post_id)
               VALUES ('$filename', '$filepath', '$filetype', '$id')";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply wrap your `$sql` and `$result` in a conditional that checks the file upload is valid before actually inserting it into your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surronding your file upload and SQL code in an if statement that checks the size of the files. An empty file should be 0.

```
if ($_FILES['images']['size'] > 0) { 
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (img_name, img_path, img_type, post_id) VALUES ('$filename', '$filepath', '$filetype', '$id')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
```

Of course, you can also check other parameters as well, not just size.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had tried something similar, but after looking at what you posted, I realized I was not putting the `move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);` within the if statement. I had also left off the `[$i]` parameter at the end and that was causing issues.

Comment: Of course! Glad I could help. Good luck with your project.